# Index that mimics full-text-index

Tags: full-text-search, update, sql-server-compact

I have a database that is retrieving information quite slowly, I asked a question and was told to use full-text-indexing, this worked, but now we switched over to a `.sdf` file and Sql Server Compact Edition 4.0 does not support full-text-indexing

Is there any index that will mimic the way a full-text-index works?

[Update and Insert Statement taking forever](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86321/update-and-insert-statement-taking-forever)

This is the code I am using:

```
 SELECT TimesUsed, Word FROM Predictions WHERE (Word LIKE @partialWord) ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC


PredTable = PredTA.GetDataByPartialWord(combo)
        If PredTable.Count = 1 Then PredTA.Update(PredTable(0).TimesUsed + 1, combo)
        If PredTable.Count = 0 Then PredTA.Insert(combo, 1)
```

Comment: You know Compact Edition is deprecated, right? Have you considered using Express with Advanced Services, which includes full-text search?

Comment: you can  cache queries in advance; for cache mechanism please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx

Comment: That post also says that full text predicates do not allow autoparameterization. It seems unlikely that cache will help with full text searches of any complexity.

Comment: @AaronBertrand if I transfer over to Sql-server Express would it be simple to transfer my .sdf database?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. What made you switch to Compact in the first place? How long ago did you do it? How much has your database really changed since then?

Comment: Database is constantly being updated, and because we were transferring the files between computers it made sense to keep it compact and switch over

Comment: See http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/migrate-a-database-to-sql-server  The focus is on moving SQL Compact to SQL Server Express or full SQL Server.

Comment: @RLF this didn't work because database is not on a website but used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267807/convert-sdf-database-to-mdf. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because [Compact Edition is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364011/61305) and doesn't support full-text search (or anything like it), I think the best solution here is to stop using Compact Edition and instead use [SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx), which includes full-text search capabilities.

Stop moving database files around between developers. [This is just dangerous](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename), regardless of whether you are using Compact Edition or proper editions of SQL Server. You should install a single instance of SQL Server, and everybody manage a single copy of the database. Use source control so that rolling back is easier than "use the copy of the file from Jimmy's machine and then add this change and take this table away..."

In order to convert back from Compact Edition to proper SQL Server, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267807/convert-sdf-database-to-mdf) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257833/convert-sdf-database-to-mdf-database).